# Remove John Wick from a list using double recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

In order for me to take over the Matrix I first need to remove John Wick from it. He is very good at hiding (obviously), so he has split himself up in a list and lists within the list. For example:

```
environment = ["a", [**"j"**, "e", **"o"**], [**"h"**, **"n"**, "s", 
    **"w"**, "o"], [**"i", "c", "k"**]]

target = "johnwick"
```

Only **double recursion** is allowed in order to remove John Wick from this list in the Matrix. He does not belong here. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
def no_wick(environment):
    target = "johnwick"
    clean_matrix = []
    if not environment:
        return clean_matrix
    elif isinstance(environment[0], list): 

        ???????

    elif environment[0] not in target:
        return clean_matrix.append(environment[0]) + no_wick(environment[1:])
    else: 
        return no_wick(environment[1:])
```

Can you help me remove John Wick from the Matrix, while I take care of Thomas A. Anderson?

Answer (score 3):

if i understand you correct, this example can help you:

```
In [1]: target = 'johnwick'

In [2]: environment = ['a', ['j', 'e', 'o'], ['h', 'n', 's', 'w', 'o'], ['i', 'c', 'k']]

In [3]: def no_wick(l, target):
   ...:     clear = []
   ...:     for x in l:
   ...:         if isinstance(x, list):
   ...:             x, target = no_wick(x, target)
   ...:             clear.append(x)
   ...:         else:
   ...:             if target.startswith(x):
   ...:                 target = target[1:]
   ...:             else:
   ...:                 clear.append(x)
   ...:     return clear, target


In [4]: no_wick(environment, target)
Out[4]: (['a', ['e'], ['s', 'o'], []], '')
```

Answer (score 1):

> Only double recursion is allowed

If my reading of this is correct, the three existing answers don't solve the problem as specified.  Instead of double recursion, they use a `for` loop to replace one of the recursions.  My guess as to what you're after:

```
environment = ["a", ["j", "e", "o"], ["h", "n", "s", "w", "o"], ["i", "c", "k"]]

target = "johnwick"

def no_wick(structure, string, letters=None):

    if letters is None:
        letters = list(string)

    if not letters or not structure:
        return structure

    head, *tail = structure

    if isinstance(head, str):
        if head == letters[0]:
            letters.pop(0)
            head = []
        else:
            head = [head]

        return head + no_wick(tail, string, letters)

    return [no_wick(head, string, letters)] + no_wick(tail, string, letters)  # the double recursion

print(no_wick(environment, target))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['a', ['e'], ['s', 'o'], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def list_purge(lst, rem):
    purged = list()
    for l in lst:
        if isinstance(l, list):
            l = list_purge(l, rem)
        else:
            for c in rem:
                l = l.replace(c, '')
        if len(l) > 0:
            purged.append(l)
    return purged
```

Should give:

```
>>>>list_purge(["a", ["j", "e", "o"], ["h", "n", "s", "w", "o"], ["i", "c", "k"]], "johnwick")
['a', ['e'], ['s']]
```

If your assignment is to leave empty strings in then just modify the code to do that.

Comment: you should leave the `o` in third sublist.

Answer (score 0):

Recurse, with a little bit of mutable parameter black magic:

```
def purge(env, target, pos=None):
    if pos is None:
        pos = [0]

    for x in env:
        if pos[0] >= len(target):
            yield x
        if isinstance(x, list):
            x = list(purge(x, target, pos=pos))
            yield x
        elif x != target[pos[0]]:
            yield x
        else:
            pos[0] += 1

env = ["a", ["j", "e", "o"], ["h", "n", "s", "w", "o"], ["i", "c", "k"]]
print(list(purge(env, "johnwick")))
```

Gives:

```
['a', ['e'], ['s', 'o'], []]
```